# Stop Visual Basic 6 from changing my casing

Tags: vb6

Very simple question that is apparently impossible to find a decent answer to: How can I make Visual Basic 6 stop changing my ^@#*ing variable casing!?!

I know that the general opinion of a great many VB users is that this "feature" is actually quite helpful, but I doubt that they use it much with any source control system. This is absolutely INFURIATING when you are trying to collaborate on a project of any significant size with several other developers. If ignored, you produce thousands of false-positive "changes" to your files (even ones with no actual code changes!) that pollute the revision history and make it near impossible in some cases to locate the actual change that took place.

If you don't ignore it (like my office, where we have been forced to implement a "no unneeded case change" policy), you spend 5x the time you would normally on each commit because you have to carefully revert out VB's "corrections" on every file, sometimes reverting hundreds of lines to put in a one line change.

Surely there must be a setting, plugin, hack, etc. out there that can remove this unwanted "feature"? I am willing to take any method I can get as long as it doesn't require me to pick through piles of phantom diffs. And to squash a couple of complaints up front: No, I can't turn off case detection in my diff tool, that's not the point. No, we can't just make the case changes globally. We're working with hundreds of thousands of LOC being worked on by multiple developers spanning many years of development. Synchronizing that is not feasible from a business standpoint. And, finally: No, we cannot upgrade to VB.net or port to another language (as much as I would love to).

(And yes, I am just a tiny bit peeved at the moment. Can you tell? My apologies, but this is costing me time and my company money, and I don't find that acceptable.)

Comment: I understand your pain, this is a huge problem with VBA, as curtisk's link shows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB6 Editor changing case of variable names!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248760/vb6-editor-changing-case-of-variable-names)

Comment: Having a Private Constant SPACE declared in one file in the project makes it impossible to use the built-in Space() function in any file in the project...

Comment: This has become one factor when weighing whether to upgrade VB6 code to C#. Not the only, not the most important, but it can push things over the line.

Comment: It's 2019... while other languages are [implementing trailing commas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas) to make diffs even cleaner, this long forsaken IDE is still gleefully flip-flopping variable casing... and I find myself here. @Toji I hope you've freed yourself of this nightmare.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a real world scenario and how we solved it for our 350k LOC VB6 project.

We are using Janus Grid and at some point all the code lines which referenced DefaultValue property of JSColumn turned to defaultValue. This was an opportunity to debug the whole IDE nuisance.

What I found was that a reference to MSXML has just been added and now the IDE picks up ISchemaAttributes' defaultValue property before the Janus Grid typelib.

After some experiments I found out that the IDE collects "registered" identifiers in the following order:

- Referenced Libraries/Projects from Project->References in the order they are listed
- Controls from Project->Components (in unknown order)
- Source Code

So the simple fix we did was to create a dummy class/interface with methods that hold our proper casing. Since we already had a project-wide typelib we referenced from every project before anything other typelib, this was painless to do.

Here is part of the IDL for our IUcsVbIntellisenseFix interface:

```
[
  odl,
  uuid(<<guid_here>>),
  version(1.0),
  dual,
  nonextensible,
  oleautomation
]
interface IUcsVbIntellisenseFix : IDispatch {
    [id(1)] HRESULT DefaultValue();
    [id(2)] HRESULT Selector();
    [id(3)] HRESULT Standalone();
    ...
}
```

We added a lot of methods to IUcsVbIntellisenseFix, some of them named after enum items we used to misspell and whatever we wanted to fix. The same can be done with a simple VB class in a common library (ActiveX DLL) that's referenced from every project.

This way our source code at some point converged to proper casing because upon check-out the IDE actually *fixed* the casing as per IUcsVbIntellisenseFix casing. Now we can't misspell enums, methods or properties even if we try to.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed response! I'll have to discuss this with the other developers at my office and see if it's a workable solution for our situation.

Comment: This would make a good answer to the "VB6 IDE tip and tricks" question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664370/your-favorite-visual-basic-6-tools-and-tips

Comment: When I tried this it worked for enums (but then again so does somewhat simpler solution above), but not for methods or properties - they keep whatever case they have in the source code, and override the case of any nearby enums. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: <quote>Since we already had a project-wide typelib we referenced from every project before anything other typelib</quote>. Notice the "before any other typelib" part. Move the fixup typelib as high as possible in References dialog, "before any other typelib".

Comment: This is a really old thread, but the problem is still there :( . Unfortunally this method didn't work for me. I've tried a simple ActiveX-DLL, made in VB6 and a registration-free DLL, made in C# - with no effect. @wqw - in what language did you create your IUcsVbIntellisenseFix-DLL?

Answer (score 25):

Depending on your situation adding

```
#If False Then
    Dim CorrectCase
#End If
```

might help.

Comment: Gives canonical case without creating a variable. Useful if enums are changing case.

Comment: Good solution for some cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I'm sure this would work great for some projects, but unfortunately I think the scale of our projects rules out this solution.

Comment: Amazing! If you just messed up one casing accidentally this will fix it for good at least in the Office 2010 VBA Editor - Thank you!!!

Comment: Actually just writing the "Dim CorrectCase" and deleting it, fixes the problem forever!

Comment: @6diegodiego9 Of all the solutions posted here and elsewhere, this is the only one that worked for me.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

SIMPLE WAY: `Dim` each variable in the case that you want.  Otherwise, `VBA` will change it in a way that is not understandable.

```
Dim x, X1, X2, y, Yy  as variant
```

in a subroutine will change ALL cases to those in the `Dim` statement

Comment: The example given is a common programming trap, where only the last item in the list is actually typed as declared all other types would be defaulted to Variants. It would not matter if you actually wanted variants, but if you did it with any other type you would get all variants and only the final item would get the declared type.

Comment: Perfect! I have been struggling with this for days until you show how to solve it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can sympathise. Luckily we're allowed to turn off case sensitivity in our version control diff tool!

It seems the VB6 IDE automatic case-correction occasionally changes case in variable declarations and references, perhaps depending on the order in which modules are listed in the VBP file? But the IDE doesn't tell you that the file needs to be saved. So the problem only shows up when you saved the file because of another edit. We briefly tried to prevent this by checking out all the files in a project and setting the case carefully, but it didn't go away.

I suppose you could list the variable names that are affected - the usual suspects are one letter names like "I", "X" and "Y", perhaps because they are used in standard event handlers like MouseDown. Then write an add-in that'll search for all declarations " As" and force the case to upper. Run the add-in on your modules before you check them in. You might be able to trigger the add-in to run automatically when you save in VB6.

EDIT: Something I've just thought of: adapt [Fred's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064858/stop-visual-basic-6-from-changing-my-casing/1064894#1064894). From now on, every time you check in a file, add a block at the top to establish canonical case for the usual suspects. If nothing else, it's easier than reverting hundreds of lines by hand. Eventually you will have this block in every file & maybe then the problem will stop happening.

```
#If False Then
  Dim I, X, Y ' etc '
#End If
```

Answer (score 2):

I standardised the case across the codebase, normally by using the examples above (`Dim CorrectCase`), and removing it again.
I then triggered VB to save EVERY file, by doing a case sensitive search/replace of "End" with "End" (no functional change, but enough to get VB to resave).
Once that was done, I could then do a single commit to standardise the case, making it MUCH easier to keep on top of it at a later date.

Answer (score 2):

In this example VB6 was changing the case of the following line following a typo I made when referencing a library: -

`Dim MyRecordset As ADODB.REcordset`

Ugly, and now every other instance of an ADODB.REcordset thus acquired the new misspelling. I fixed this as follows: -

1. Type in a new declaration as follows

   `Dim VB6CasingSucks AS ADODB, Recordset`

   Note the comma and space after ADODB. Hit [ENTER] for VB6 to check the line.
2. At this point all instances of REcordset change back to Recordset.
3. Delete your new declaration.

I don't know if this fix will help with enums/other variable names.

Answer (score 0):

**Specifically for controlling the case of enum values**, there is a VB6 IDE add-in which may be helpful. Enums seem to have a slightly unique version of this problem.

As described in the link below:

> The VB6 IDE has an annoying quirk when it comes to the case of Enum
>   members. Unlike with other identifiers, the IDE doesn't enforce the
>   case of an Enum member as it was declared in the Enum block. That
>   occasionally causes an Enum member that was manually written to lose
>   its original case, unless a coder typed it carefully enough. 
>   ...
>
> However, if a project contains a lot of Enums and/or a particular Enum
>   has a lot of members, redeclaring the members in each of them can get
>   quite tedious fast. ...

Ref: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?778109-VB6-modLockEnumCase-bas-Enforce-Case-of-Enums

> ...load and unload the add-in as needed via the Add-In Manager
>   dialog box. Usage is as simple as selecting the entire Enum block,
>   right-clicking and then choosing the "Lock Enum Case" context menu
>   item.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem:

in a bas module there I wrote :

```
Private sub bla_bla()
  Dim K as integer
End Sub
```

so in a class module the `Dim k as integer` will automatically be replaced by IDE become 'Dim K as integer' <-- it's not logical but then:
I correct the bas module become:

```
Private sub bla_bla()
  Dim k as integer
End Sub
```

then magically the problem in the class module was solved (still be k and not automatically replaced by IDE become K).  Sorry I'm poor in English

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there's any to do it.  The IDE will change the case of the variable name to whatever it is when it's declared.  But, honestly, back in the day I worked on several large VB6 projects and never found this to be a problem.  Why are people on your development team constantly changing variable declarations?  It seems like you have not established a clear variable naming policy that you enforce.  I know your upset, so no offense, but it might be your policies that are lacking in this regard.

Unfortunately, according to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226565/alternative-ide-for-vb6), alternate VB6 IDEs are hard to come by.  So, your best bet is to solve this problem via policy.  Or move to VB.NET. :)

Comment: Yes, a variable naming policy does help some, it does not solve the problem. Third party libraries can wreck havoc on a naming policy, causing the case to change project wide, sending you straight back into the same cycle (as Toji stated in the reply to U62's answer).

Comment: @Miquella Well, if a third party library does not follow Microsoft naming convention, then it does not deserve to be used... So a policy could be to ban such libraries.

Comment: @Phil1970 what nonsense, even Microsoft doesn't abide by their own naming convention, at least no back in the day when vb6 was new. And you really are blind if you think Microsoft naming conventions are the only conventions available. Not everything is developed in a Microsoft language, and Microsoft never set a fixed convention for third party libraries. for instance, in VB6 we use Hungarian notation like convention for private variables/functions and camelcase for public properties/methods on classes/controls.

Answer (score -9):

Wow. I've spent a lot of time programming in VB6 and I have no idea what you're on about. The only thing I can think you're referring to is that intellisense will change the capitalization of variable names to match their declarations. If you're complaining about that, I would have to wonder why the hell they've been entered any other way to begin with. And if that is your problem, no, there's no way to disable it that I'm aware of. I'd suggest you, in one go, check out every file, make sure the caps on the declarations and uses of variables all match and check back in.

Comment: Exactly. If anything, then the fellow developers are the ones changing the ^@#*ing variable casing. The VBA IDE just makes it consistent.

Comment: Wow, what a quick down-vote. Seems like someone does not like to see this answer at +1.

Comment: Guess you didn't read the question and see how large his project is, this answer is obviously completely unworkable in his situation.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: Obviously I'm from the "I have no idea what you are talking about" fraction. Which may be because I have (admittedly) never worked on a VB6 project of that size. So, *when exactly* does VB6 arbitrarily change variable name casing?

Comment: One major flaw with this is that several of the third party libraries we use have a different naming convention than our own code, causing the case to change matching the third party library or back to our own, depending on what order VB loads the files in. To make this even worse, some of the third party libraries use different naming conventions between them. This, in addition to problems like the enumeration casing rules (described in the link that curtisk provided) make case control in complex projects very difficult.

Comment: @Toji: I thought variable names are bound to the scope the variable is used in? How could the third party naming convention in a different module affect your own? I guess I'm just lacking experience here, but I genuinely don't get it.

Comment: I thought that originally as well, but we have seen evidence in our system of cross-module case changes occurring, and have heard other developers cite similar problems. If it truly was scoped to the current file it wouldn't be a problem, but unfortunately that's just not the case.

Comment: @U62 I guess you then never really developed with third party libraries, which have different naming conventions, as that can wreak havoc with your own code. for instance, if you have a method called GetWindow() but a third party library has one called getWindow(), then it's possible you run into this problem. To be honest, I still think this is a major BUG in the VB6/VBA IDE, it should register the naming per object/routine. It has something to do with how it stores variable names in memory as it also has a limit which you can run into when you have a large project.