# Configure Git Extensions to ignore case changes in files

Tags: git, ignore, case-insensitive

I use VB6 and Git Extensions. I do have a problem that VB6 environment tends to change variable names from upper case to lower case and vice verse.
In Git diff it makes a large mess to see actual diffs.

Can you give an advice how to set Git Extension to ignore changes in cases?

Comment: **Turn off that auto-rename feature in VB.** _Whithout having searched for the latest Git fork_: No, such a Git feature makes no sense, not in Git nor in Git-Extensions because Git is a dumb content tracker for text and binary files. Git has no notion about the contents (which would be neccessary). Git or such extensions would need to understand the content and not ignore case changes in strings for examples. Futher: Git tracks changes per line - what if the variabel name changes and the text in the string on the right hand too? What a mess.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064858/stop-visual-basic-6-from-changing-my-casing there is no good solution to turn off auto-rename.
Git allows to set external diff tools and, for example, Winmerge has an option to upper case and lower case.