# Random case change in the code between form

Tags: vb6

In the code itself (so not in the .FRM or .VBP .OCX declaration section) some controls change their case (apparently randomly) after saving any modification :

```
-    If Me.CC_Absence = 1 Then Me.CC_REMPLACABLE = 0
+    If Me.CC_ABSENCE = 1 Then Me.CC_REMPLACABLE = 0
```

or

```
-    Me.GR_CRITERE.Visible = False
+    Me.GR_Critere.Visible = False
```

then the source control report change and ask for commit... Is it possible to get rid of that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop Visual Basic 6 from changing my casing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064858/stop-visual-basic-6-from-changing-my-casing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That one is not a registry problem, it's due to a real bug in VB6 : at least another control in the project in **another** form and/or module with the same spelling have a different case.

Which case (upper/lower) will be retained for the code probably depend on the loading order of forms and/or modules and the last one seen is taken as a reference for the case...

Anyway, if you want to avoid that effect you should name all the same spelling controls in forms and/or modules in the project with the exactly same case.